# SQL CMD: pass variables with brackets and single quotes

Tags: sql-server, variables, escaping, sqlcmd

I am trying to create a script that gives me the size of some databases.
I have created the original query which works but now i want to make it dynamically.

My script creates a temp table based on the variable that was submitted.
for example:

```
        create table #temptbl (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), valuex varchar(256))
        INSERT INTO #temptbl (valuex) values ('PARTS'),('PARTS_Master'),('PARTS2_4'),('PARTS2_7'),('Projects')
```

The rest of the script then loops over the rows in this table and gives me the size of each corresponding database.

I was looking into passing a variable in sqlcmd like so:

```
sqlcmd -v variables ="('PARTS'),('PARTS_Master'),('PARTS2_4'),('PARTS2_7'),('Projects')" -S MYSERVERNAME\sqlexpress -i DatabaseSize.sql -d Parts
```

and then in my sql script I changed it like this:

```
        create table #tables (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), valuex varchar(256))
        INSERT INTO #tables (valuex) values '$(variables)'
```

This however gives me an error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server ServerName\SQLEXPRESS, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: You can't replace a list of values with a variable like that. That's not how SQL Works.

Comment: hi Larnu, I can. It works now thanks to the answer of Dan Guzman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
create table #tables (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), valuex varchar(256))
INSERT INTO #tables (valuex) values '$(variables)'
```

After variable substitution, it becomes:

```
create table #tables (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), valuex varchar(256))
INSERT INTO #tables (valuex) values '('PARTS'),('PARTS_Master'),('PARTS2_4'),('PARTS2_7'),('Projects')'
```

Note the list of row constructors is enclosed in single quotes, resulting in invalid T-SQL syntax. So the solution is to simply remove the quotes around the SQLCMD variable:

```
CREATE TABLE #tables (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), valuex varchar(256))
INSERT INTO #tables (valuex) VALUES $(variables);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my issue, now i feel bad for not asking it two hours ago, i thought my issue was with the sqlcmd script.

Comment: @KevinJoos or @Dan, I am trying to run a similar sqlcmd command, but am running into issues. If you are available please check out my post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615575/sqlcmd-pass-multiple-values-in-a-variable-to-a-temp-table`